# Number Fields Arising from Newforms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, reference-request

It is well-known that, given a normalized eigenform $f=\sum a_n q^n$, its coefficients $a_n$ generate a number field $K_f$.

In their 1995 [paper](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf) "Fermat's Last Theorem", Darmon, Diamond, and Taylor remark that, at the time of writing, very little was known about what sort of number fields could arise as some $K_f$. They do claim, however, that $K_f$ must be totally real or CM. This claim is made just before Lemma 1.37, on page 40 of the copy I linked to.

This is probably standard knowledge among experts, but I'm having trouble finding a reference, so my questions are:

1) Can someone please provide a reference for this claim?

2) Is this still the state of the art, or do we now know more about what types of fields can appear as $K_f$ for some $f$? What if we restrict our attention to weight $k=2$?

Thank you!

> Edit: In my question, I originally just wrote "modular form" instead of "normalized eigenform". Thanks to @Stopple for pointing this out! Also, I originally claimed the paper was published in 2007, but Kevin Buzzard pointed out it was published in 1995. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (1), see Ribet's wonderful article *Galois representations attached to eigenforms with Nebentypus* (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0063943). It's proposition 3.2.

Comment: See also item 53 in http://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/.

Answer (score 5):

It's not true for any old modular form.  Since the forms live in a vector space over $\mathbb C$, you can achieve any complex number as a coefficient.

Here's a partial answer to what is true.  You need to have a cusp form that is an eigenfunction of the Hecke operators, normalized so the leading coefficient is $1$.  Since the Hecke operators are self adjoint in the Peterson (sp?) inner product, the eigenvalues are real, and one can show these are the coefficients in the $q$ expansion as follows:  for $p$ prime, the $m$th coefficient of $T_p f$ is $a_{mp}$, for all $m$, more or less from the definition of $T_p$.  This is also $\lambda_p a_m$, and from this and $a_1=1$ one deduces $a_p=\lambda_p$ (take $m=1$.)  The general case follows from the recursion for powers of primes, and multiplicativity.

This answer is not quite right because it doesn't explain how CM extensions can arise, but it's a start.

Comment: Hi Stopple, good point. It's a bad habit, but in my mind, when I say modular form I (almost) always mean "normalized eigenform", or even just "newform", but certainly the way I stated my question is incorrect. I'll fix my question to make it more precise. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: The Hecke operators are self-adjoint for $\Gamma_0(N)$; however when dealing with forms with a character (e.g. eigenforms) the Hecke operators are only self-adjoint "up to a twist", from which one deduces that $\overline{a}_n=\chi(n)^{-1}a_n$, and the claim follows from this. PS Jeff H: I remember reading that paper in 1995, which makes me a bit skeptical about the claim that it was published in 2007! 

Comment: @Kevin Buzzard: Oh! You're absolutely right -- I see on Darmon's website that it was indeed published in 1995. I guess the tex file was recompiled in 2007, leading to the date I cited from this version of the paper: www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf  Thanks!